# Issue with calculating time within FreeRTOS taskENTER_CRITICAL and taskEXIT_CRITICAL

Tags: arm, freertos

I am running FreeRTOS on Arm Cortex M7, with following config:

```
#define configPRIO_BITS             3
#define configLIBRARY_LOWEST_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY         0xf

#define configLIBRARY_MAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY    5

#define configKERNEL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY     ( configLIBRARY_LOWEST_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY << (8 - configPRIO_BITS) )

#define configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY    ( configLIBRARY_MAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY << (8 - configPRIO_BITS) )
```

When I am calculating time for some data transfer using the task critical sections, it is giving wrong value (~300us):

```
taskENTER_CRITICAL();
{
 startTime = xTaskGetCurrentTimeInUsFromISR();
 // Read data from card
 doDATAtransfer();
 endTime = xTaskGetCurrentTimeInUsFromISR();
 netTime = endTime - startTime; //~300us
}
taskEXIT_CRITICAL();
```

If I don't use the critical sections then it is giving correct and expected value as ~8000us.
This seems like if I measure the time with all interrupt disabled, it is giving wrong time.

Can anyone please help me understand what could be issue here?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer! Today morning, I went for jogging and somehow it clicked to me. Here it is:
Since systick interrupt has the lowest priority, the systick ISR will not get executed within those critical sections and due to which it will not give correct value.

Comment: yes, basically `taskENTER_CRICITCAL` should disable interrupts globaly - so no IRQ from your system timer can be invoked..